# Evaluate the iterated integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

Evaluate the iterated integral:

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^1 (2x+y)^8 \,dxdy$$

I tried doing a u-sub by letting u = 2x+y but then once I got to the outer integral I got $$\int_0^2 (2+y)^9/18 - y^9/18 \, dy$$ which I don't know how to integrate. Any feedback would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply do the substitution $z = y+2$, there, done.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^2 (2+y)^9/18 - y^9/18 \, dy  =\int_0^2 (2+y)^9/18  dy -\int _0^2 y^9/18 \, dy$$

you may deal with each integral separately.